# Crashlytics record error

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am recording an error using Crashlytics for iOS.

```
NSDictionary *detail = @{@"message":errorWithURL, @"response":jsonString};
[[Crashlytics sharedInstance] recordError:[NSError errorWithDomain:@"send request" code:0 userInfo:detail]];
```

But I do not see the message in Crashlytics console.

See [here](http://crashes.to/s/781fc05236b).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Fabric Docs - "Data contained within the userInfo object are converted to key-value pairs and displayed in the keys/logs section within an individual issue."

So press "View all sessions" button upper right corner, then go to keys/logs section on top of the page

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html#using-the-api

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you uploaded DSYM file with your build. 
If the DSYM file was supposed to be uploaded via a Fastlane job, then the upload might have failed.