# Logging Additional Information for Error Reporting

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, google-fabric

In our error logging, we are using `Crashlytics`.

Now there are 2 ways that we log errors:

1. The automatic logging (when the app has crashed) done when the app starts up again.
2. Immediate logging using the Swift SDK

In case 1. it seems that there is no way of logging additional information.

However, in case 2. we use the following call :

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error, withAdditionalUserInfo:additionalInfo)
```

With `additionalInfo` being a simple set of KVP's `["ListingNumber": "abcAsEasyAs123"]`

However, this does not show up on the portal as well as in the `.txt` download that they offer.

We then amended our logging method to try and attach the additional info to the error itself.

```
if let error = error {            
    let newError = NSError(domain: (error as NSError).domain, code: (error as NSError).code, userInfo: ["ListingNumber": "abcAsEasyAs123"])
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(newError)
}
```

However, even in this case, the additional info is nowhere to be found.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html#using-the-api), this should be possible, but nothing I am doing is showing.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of that question as I have read it and referenced the same material that the accepted answer used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics record error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081139/crashlytics-record-error)

Comment: @Honey I have read that one, and as you can see, I included the referenced page from the API in my question.

Comment: @DavidPilkington did you try with `CLSLogv`?

Comment: Do you log the errors in the main app project, or in a framework used by the app project? I've had problems getting errors logged in frameworks to show up in Crashlytics. Also, make sure that you have selected "All events" in Crashlytics instead of "Crashes" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917084/crashlytics-not-logging-errors-in-framework

Comment: @DavidPilkington check this https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html?highlight=clslogv

Comment: @ReinierMelian my understanding is that CLSLogv does not do anything in release mode?

Comment: console logs are silenced in Release but is reported in crashlog in both modes @DavidPilkington

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. The additional information should be present within the specific crash. If you click on "View all sessions", do you see the custom information under keys or logs?

Comment: @MikeBonnell, I managed to get that part working. But I also need to add the additional information on fatal crashes. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I would need to look into your specific app to see what's going on. Can you email support(at)fabric(dot)io with the bundle id of your app?